# What purpose does congestion control achieve, and how does it work?

Tags: relays, security, protocol

I am trying to understand exactly how the different solutions for the congestion control mechanism work and what purpose they achieve.

With "the solutions" I mean the circuit level throttling and the stream level throttling.

English is not my first language which might be the cause to why I don't understand this clear enough.
To make it easy to answer, I'll provide a couple of links I am reading.

http://cnds.eecs.jacobs-university.de/courses/nds-2008/moradlou-tor.pdf (page 14)
http://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/~abc/teaching/bil656/presentations/OzlemKahramanEr.pdf (page 10)